Is there a German equivalent for the English expression "I know one when I see one?"
I have a few instances of the phrase "I know a [noun] when I see one" in a translation project I am working on, specifically

I know a thief when I see one. [The speaker is addressing a thief.]

and

I know a bribe when I see one.

Am I right in thinking this is an English idiom which should not be translated literally? Is there a German idiom equivalent to this?

Is this the same expression that was famously used when the US Supreme Court tried to define obscenity ("I know it when I see it.")? Or do you see a difference between your examples and this phrase?

The only straight equivalent that comes into my mind: "ich erkenne ihn sofort" where "sofort" means "at once" and expresses the (proud) posture of the speaker arguing that he/she has a lot of experience (or some kind of high awareness) dealing with human behaviour.

A slightly old-fashioned idiomatic expression is

Ich kenne meine Pappenheimer.

It originates in a play by Friedrich Schiller, where General Wallenstein, in deep distress, is expressing his relief about the loyalty of some troops from Pappenheim. The meaning of the phrase has completely lost any relation to this origin. As the meaning of Pappenheimer is widely not understood any longer (interpreting it in a literal manner leads to "those from the home of cardboard", which is seen as a strange and slightly funny expression), over time the phrase was interpreted as expressing suspicion. Nowadays, the phrase expresses something along the lines of "I am looking through you", or "I won't be fooled", or "I know one when I see one".
Another expression with a similar meaning, from Berlin slang, is

Nachtigall, ick hör dir trapsen.

Literally it means "Nightingale, I hear you trampeling". It expresses that somebody suspects unfavorable upcoming events (such as being fooled, or being cheated). In a more general sense, it is also used to express "I am looking through you".
Notice the ick (instead of standard German ich) and the dative case of dir, which would be considered wrong in standard German (hören stands with accusative case), which marks this as Berlin dialect.

It may be an anglicism similar to "es macht Sinn" (a literal translation of an English phrase used often enough for it to become common in German), but at least phrases like

Ich erkenne einen ..., wenn ich ihn sehe.

are quite common in contemporary German. So yes, a literal translation works. I'm not aware of an idiom that would be equivalent.

But in German it is not this generic. It is rather used with a clear stereotype:
Ich erkennen einen Lügner, wenn ich ihn sehe.
So you usually do not recognize all if you see them.

It's not fitting in all circumstances, but a large part of the idiom is that the speaker is absolutely sure about a person. If he has no compuction to tell them to their face, he may say:

Ich sage Dir auf den Kopf zu, dass Du ein Dieb bist.

Note that this is always adressed at a person. Your bribe example would accordingly be aimed at the briber:

Ich sage ihm auf den Kopf zu, dass er sie bestochen hat.

